# Why am I getting a "cannot convert from 'HTMLWriter.HeadingElement' to 'HTMLWriter.TextElement[]'" error in Program.cs - C#, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I am getting an "cannot convert from 'HTMLWriter.HeadingElement' to 'HTMLWriter.TextElement[]'" error in my Program.cs class.

namespace HTMLWriter
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Converter c = new Converter(@"C:\data\poem.txt", @"C:\data\poem.html");
c.convert();

```
        c = new Converter(@"C:\data\quotes.txt", @"C:\data\quotes.html");
        c.convert();
    }

    public static void example()
    {
        HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
        HeadElement head = new HeadElement();
        head.Title = new TitleElement("This is a title");
        doc.Head = head;
        doc.Body = new BodyElement();
        doc.Body.Add(new HeadingElement("This is a heading")); //error
        doc.Body.Add(new ParagraphElement("This is a paragraph")); //error
        doc.Body.Add(new ParagraphElement(null)); //error
        doc.Body.Add(new ParagraphElement("This is a paragraph too")); //error
        Console.WriteLine(doc.Render());
    }
}
```

}

namespace HTMLWriter
{
class BodyElement : HTMLElement
{
private List _elements = new List();

```
    public void Add(TextElement[] element)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < element.Length; i++)
        {
            _elements.Add(element[i]);
        }
    }
    public override string Render()
    {
        if(_elements.Count == 0)
        {
            return "<body>\n </body>";
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < _elements.Count; i++)
        {
            return "<body>" + _elements[i] + "</body>";
        }

        return "<body>\n</body>";
    }
}
```

}

namespace HTMLWriter
{
class HeadingElement : TextElement
{
public HeadingElement(string text) : base(text)
{
Text = text;
}
public override string Render()
{
if(Text == null)
{
return "

";
}

```
        return "<h1>" + Text + "</h1>";
    }
}
```

}

namespace HTMLWriter
{
class ParagraphElement : TextElement
{
public ParagraphElement(string text) : base(text)
{
Text = text;
}

```
    public override string Render()
    {
        if(Text == null)
        {
            return "<p></p>";
        }
        return "<p>" + Text + "</p>";
    }
}
```

}

namespace HTMLWriter
{
abstract class TextElement : HTMLElement
{
private string _text;
public string Text
{
get { return _text; }
set { _text = value; }
}
public TextElement(string text)
{
Text =  text;
}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Add method takes an array of TextElements.

```
public void Add(TextElement[] element)
```

But you are calling the method with only one TextElement;

```
doc.Body.Add(new HeadingElement("This is a heading"));`
```

If you want to do both, I would suggest renaming the `Add` method to `AddRange` , then add a new `Add` method as per below;

```
public void Add(TextElement element)
{
    _elements.Add(element);
}
```